# Software (web-app or iOS) to maintain and visualize data an relationships for food and dishes

Tags: web-apps, data-visualization, data

I would like to maintain data sets of foods and visualize their relation to dishes.

As an Avocado, I would use it in a salad or on a slice of bread.
An Orange I would use to make fresh juice or in a salad
A grapefruit for fresh juice.
A pomegranate for fresh juice.

I then need some kind of visualization, like if I click the category salad, it would show me avocado and oranges. If I click the dish 'fresh pressed juice' it shows me orange, grapefruit, and pomegranate.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried [grocy](https://grocy.info/) and it can create relationships between recipes and ingredients.

However, be warned, it's very very feature-rich, which involves a tedious getting started phase where you have to populate the ingredients and recipes table by yourself.